# Firebase Android setup issue

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to setup firebase in my android app am getting following error..

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.<init>()' is inaccessible to class 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzg'
```

Here is my code

```
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);
```

Comment: I found the issue I was missing     compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0'  ,this one was not in the document though

Answer (score 0):

You should include latest android support library in gradle script.

Comment: These are my dependencies                                compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:11.2.0'